# User Defined Function - sum with iterative calculation

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, finance

I am writing a vba code to calculate the interests paid between two periods

I have written this code but it always give me back the value 0.

```
Function interests_paid_between(rate As Double, firstPer As Integer, lastPer As Integer, NPER As Integer, PV As Double) As Variant

Dim FutureValue As Double
FutureValue = InputBox("What is the future value of the loan? (if it is 0 put 0 else the value)")

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = firstPer To lastPer
        InterestPaid = InterestPaid + IPmt(rate, i, NPER, PV, FutureValue)
    Next i

    interests_paid_between = InterestPaid

End Function
```

Also, I need to include an option where the future value is no equal to 0.

Could you help me with this?

Comment: Have you stepped through it to make sure all of the parameters have a value?

Answer (score 0):

Using `Application.InputBox()`:

```
Function interests_paid_between(rate As Double, firstPer As Integer, lastPer As Integer, NPER As Integer, PV As Double) As Variant

    Dim FutureValue As Double
    FutureValue = Application.InputBox("What is the future value of the loan? (if it is 0 put 0 else the value)", Type:=1)

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = firstPer To lastPer
        InterestPaid = InterestPaid + IPmt(rate, i, NPER, PV, FutureValue)
    Next i

    interests_paid_between = InterestPaid

End Function
```

In a cell entered:

```
=interests_paid_between(0.05,1,5,12,-1000)
```

and inputting *1200* I get:

[image]

I don't know if the calculation is correct, but at least it's not zero.